# Form tag conflicting with Jquery functions

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm a newbee, and I just sense, after a bit of research, that this one is way over my head so I'm just going to ask away.

The following Jfiddle shows the code working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/s1tp8t59/2/   - the jquery in it, that is.  However when i surround the html with form tags it seems to completely mess up the jquery.

I'll indicate in the code below where I'm adding the form tags.

HTML

```
<div id = "container">


<form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = "post">

<div id = "invoice_header">

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
<label for="name" class = "ih1">To</label>
<input id="to" type="text" value="" name="to">
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px; ">
<label for="date" class = "ih1">Date</label>
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" value="" name="date">
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
<label for="duedate" class = "ih1">Due Date</label>
<input id="duedate" type="datetime-local" value="" name="duedate">
</div>

<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px;">
<label for="invoice" class = "ih1">Invoice</label>
<input id="invoice" type="text" value="" name="invoice">
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
<label for="reference" class = "ih1">Reference</label>
<input id="reference" type="text" value="" name="reference">
</div>

</div> 



    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Item</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" style = "visibility: hidden; font-family: Sans Serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;">Add</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Description</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Qty</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Unit Price</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Disc %</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Account</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" style = "visibility: hidden; font-family: Sans Serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;">Add</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Tax Rate</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" style = "visibility: hidden; font-family: Sans Serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;">Add</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="item" class = "ih2">Amount</label>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" name = "sales[1][item]" size = "12">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="item">Add</button>
    <div class = "dropmenu"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][description]"  size="40">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][qty]" size="4">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][price]" size="6">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][disc]" size="4">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][account]" size="24">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="valueHolder">Add</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name= "sales[1][taxrate]"size="16">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="valueHolder">Add</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sales[1][amount]" size="12">
  </td>
  <td><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 <div id = "submitposition">
 <input type = "submit" submit = "addsales" class = "submit">
 </div>

 </form>




<div id = "morebutton">
<button class="add_field_button">Add add a new line</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1tp8t59/3/)**.

That happen since you `add` button will act as a submit button and refresh your page on click, if you surrended it by form, to avoid that you have to specify the `type='button'`, so in your HTML code the button should be like :

```
<td>
    <button class="item" type="button">Add</button>
    <div class = "dropmenu"></div>
</td>
```

And in your JS code like:

```
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>....<button class="item" type="button">Add</button>...');
```

Hope this helps.